# Transpose multiple columns into single column

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google sheet in which the rows are unique cities and the columns are years. It can grow in two dimensions.

```
|            |         2010         |          2011        |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|    City    | Temp low | Temp high | Temp low | Temp high |
-----------------------------------------------------------
| London     |    10    |     11    |    21    |     22    |
| Birmingham |    12    |     13    |    23    |     24    |
```

However, this double header doesn't work for creating a pivot table.

How can I transform the table such that it grows only in the row dimension and the years are simply a value in a single column?

```
|    City    | Year | Temp low | Temp high |
-------------------------------------------
| London     | 2010 |    10    |     11    |
| Birmingham | 2010 |    12    |     13    |
| London     | 2011 |    21    |     22    |
| Birmingham | 2011 |    23    |     24    |
```

Here is a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T-7znG0FyZ25OqCLVx8GMmjqqE6E7pdn2TwFzZk_n3M/edit?usp=sharing) of the above example.

The formula shouldn't need to be adapted when new rows or columns are added. However, the column pattern will remain the same and can be relied on.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following formula

```
=QUERY({{"Year";ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(" ",REPT(B1:E1&" ",COUNTA(A3:A)))," ")))}, 
              query({A2:A,B2:C;A3:A,D3:E}, 
                     "where Col1 is not null",1)}, 
          "select Col2, Col1, Col3, Col4 order by Col1, Col2",1)
```

If you want to order by city and then by year use

```
=QUERY({{"Year";ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(" ",REPT(B1:E1&" ",COUNTA(A3:A)))," ")))}, 
              query({A2:A,B2:C;A3:A,D3:E}, 
                     "where Col1 is not null",1)}, 
          "select Col2, Col1, Col3, Col4 order by Col2, Col1",1)
```

[image]

*(The above formula is actually a modified version of [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/129650/117311). Please refer to it for more info and how the formula works.)*

Comment: Thanks! Is there a possibility to make this formula adaptive? Currently, it needs to be extended manually if there are new year columns added. Imagine I have 20 more columns to the right...

Comment: Sure. You just add groups like `A3:A,F3:G;A3:A,H3:I;A3:A,J3:K` and so on. You also need to adjust your `REPT` values to `B1:K1`. I could show you at your test sheet but it is view only.

Comment: *"Thanks!"* 
Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't scale and is error prone. I need a formula that doesn't need changing when I add new columns.

Comment: Fair enough. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

So, turns out, the general problem is called "Unpivoting". Unfortunately there is no function in Google Sheets yet.

I found the following answers useful.

### Manual

[UNPIVOT function in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50231860/unpivot-function-in-google-sheets)

[How do you create a “reverse pivot” in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55503908/2607891)

### Using Script

[How do you create a “reverse pivot” in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43681525/2607891)

### Other

[Transpose Ranges repeated by row](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115804/transpose-ranges-repeated-by-row)

[Converting multiple columns to list](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/137085/converting-multiple-columns-to-list?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Analyse multiple columns per row](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/129597/analyse-multiple-columns-per-row?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Split columns in to rows in google spread sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/119793/split-columns-in-to-rows-in-google-spread-sheets?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Transpose names across multiple columns/rows into a single column in Google Sheet with twist](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/149048/transpose-names-across-multiple-columns-rows-into-a-single-column-in-google-shee?rq=1)